# does not match sequence type: xs:integer

Tags: database, schema, xquery

I am just running a simple test for function in XQuery. Below is my code:

```
**declare function local:degreeofmatch($p as element(postings)) as xs:integer
{
    let $q := $p//reqSkill
    return $q/@level
};**

local:degreeofmatch(doc("posting.xml")/postings)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
alax-run q8.xq

Type Error: Type of value '
()
' does not match sequence type: xs:integer
At File "q8.xq", line 1, characters 65-75
At File "q8.xq", line 7, characters 19-48
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the xml? That error message suggests that the XPath expressions are not finding anything, but the error could be in any of several different places.

Answer (score 1):

Your function declares that it will return a single `xs:integer` value, however it looks like you are attempting to return a sequence of untyped values.

However your query is not actually matching any data which is why you see the error:

```
Type of value '
()
' does not match sequence type: xs:integer
```

In that message `()` denotes the *empty sequence*, which indicates that you did not match any data.

I have updated your function to correctly return a sequence of *zero or more* `xs:integer`:

```
declare function local:degreeofmatch($p as element(postings)) as xs:integer*
{
    let $q := $p//reqSkill
    return
        $q/xs:integer(@level)
};

local:degreeofmatch(doc("posting.xml")/postings)
```

There are many reasons why your query might not match any data, but two common ones are:

1) Have you provided the correct URI to the `doc` function for your `posting.xml` document?
You could use the `doc-available` function to check this.

2) Is your data in a namespace?
You are currently querying the default namespace; If you want to search any namespace, you could use `/*:posting` instead of `/posting` and `//*:reqSkill` instead of `//reqSkill`